# Choose item from a IPTV playlist on startup

Tags: vlc-media-player, iptv

I want to open a specific channel on an IPTV m3u playlist using vlc. To do so I must first go Media/Open Network Stream and then go View/Playlist to manually select the channel I want to view.

If I know in advance the channel I want to play, is there a VLC command I could run to go directly to a specific channel without having to manually select it?

Answer (score 0):

This command will open vlc and run the specified channel number

"C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "http://freeiptvdaily.net:8000/live/jKRuktLOCJ/freeiptvdaily.tv/**CHANNELNUMBER**.ts"